# Disabled DropDownList razor mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

In my razor view, I use a drop down list. I want to have this control disabled (not selectable).

My code is:

```
<div class="field-list">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre, Model.LinguaMadreList, new{ @disabled = "disabled" })</div>
```

But it doesn't work, my control is always enabled. Html page code is:

```
<select name="LinguaCodiceMadre" id="LinguaCodiceMadre" data-val-length-max="10" data-val-length="The field LinguaCodiceMadre must be a string with a maximum length of 10." data-val="true">
    <option></option>
    <option value="sq">Albanian</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="it">Italian</option>
    <option value="pt">Portuguese</option>
    <option value="ru">Russian</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

without the "disabled" attribute.

My real goal is to enable/disable dropdown conditionally, something like this:

```
<div class="field-list">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre, Model.LinguaMadreList, new{@disabled=Model.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "false"})</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried both with

```
new{@disabled=Model.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "false"}
```

and

```
new{disabled=Model.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "false"}
```

but nothing, disabled attribute is not rendering on html page.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What is the return type of `Model.LinguaMadreList`?

Comment: `code` public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LinguaMadreList { get; set; }

Comment: Sorry, forgot to also ask what is the type of `model.LinguaCodiceMadre`?

Comment: No problem ...
`code`
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string LinguaCodiceMadre { get; set; }

Comment: Why don't you want to use the disabled attribute?

Comment: @LeeEnglestone I dont think the OP is saying that, he is saying the `disabled` attribute is not rendering.

Comment: @disabled should be disabled . Then it will work fine . #tested

Comment: @nolanofra does this code render the `disabled` attribute? `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre,new SelectList(new []{"1","2"}),new {@disabled="disabled"})`

Comment: @mxmissile I tried with `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre,new SelectList(new []{"1","2"}),new {@disabled="disabled"})`, but it doesn't work. 
Html rendered is:
`<select id="LinguaCodiceMadre" name="LinguaCodiceMadre">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>`

Comment: Can you post your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue: there was a javascript in my code (I'm sorry, I did not notice right away) deleting disable attribute at document ready.

What I did is:

- creating an extension for HtmlHelper:

---

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionText, bool canEdit)
    {
        if (canEdit) return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionText);
            return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionText, new { @disabled = "disabled" });
    }
}
```

- In razor view:

---

```
<code><div class="field-list">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre, Model.LinguaMadreList, "", Model.IsEnabled)</div></code>
```

This works!

Thanks

Comment: what if I also need to give id and class in new { html attributes }, then how it is going to be generic

Comment: My answer to the same question, which preserves any { html attributes} passed from the HTML/Markup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47597356/1906278

Answer (score 12):

Just a small correction . Try this

```
<div class="field-list">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre, Model.LinguaMadreList, new{ disabled = "disabled" })</div>
```

This will surely disable your Drop-down ..

**well other alternative is using jquery :**

declare **@Id** for your control later do something like this

```
$("#youid").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Finally try  this :** If this wont work means problem from your side

```
<div class="field-list">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LinguaCodiceMadre, Model.LinguaMadreList,String.Empty, new{ disabled = "disabled" })</div>
```

Regards

Comment: I confirmed `@disabled="disabled"` also works with MVC5.

Comment: w3schools html for dropdown disable http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_disabled

Comment: Issue still exists.

I tried both with 

    new{@disabled=Model.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "false"}

and 
   

    new{disabled=Model.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "false"}

but nothing, disabled attribute is not rendering on html page.

Answer (score 5):

First, If you want to Enable/Disable DropDown List based on user input, You need to use javascript to Enable/Disable Drop Down List.

For Javascript Use Following Logic :

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function () {

  if (document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked == true) {

     document.getElementById("DropDown1").disabled = true;
  }
  else {

     document.getElementById("DropDown1").disabled = false;
  }

});
```

Here is Fiddle Demo that I tried for you which is worling Perfectly

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3H5xN)

1. I have model with two Properties
2. I am populating Test Data in DropDown in Controller For Demo Purpose(In your case it will come from Database)
3. On the View, I am assigning IDs to both Inputs.
4. And at Last, In the view Below there is Javascript Function that is driving CheckBox to see wether is checked or no, If It is Checked, You can not select any Values from DropDown else it is open to Select Values.