# Disable/Enable for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have checked many of previous questions about this problem, but couldn't figure it out how to solve it in the way I want.

I have a DropDownList element which is a Html Helper in my view and I want to render it as disabled or enables depending upon a condition. Here is the html attributes which I created to achieve this goal;

```
new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = item.isRecordActive == 0 ? "true" : "false"}
```

However, it does not work. It renders all of the dropdowns as disabled in my view and doesn't care about the condition.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabled DropDownList razor mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123852/disabled-dropdownlist-razor-mvc)

Comment: isRecordActive is it in Model bool or integer?

Comment: @disabled = item.isRecordActive == 0 ? "true" : "false" is works fine If isRecordActive is integer.

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper, integer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
(item.isRecordActive == 0) ? 
new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } :
new { @class = "form-control" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
 public enum DropDownValue{A,B,C,D}
 public class TestDropDown
 {
    public DropDownValue MuValue { get; set; }
    public int ShowMe { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller/Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestDropDown tdd = new TestDropDown();
        tdd.MuValue = DropDownValue.A;
        tdd.ShowMe = 0;           
        return View(tdd);
    }
```

View:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
       My DropDown:@Html.DropDownList("MyList", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DropDownValue))), new  { @disabled = Model.ShowMe != 0 ? "true" : "false" })

    </div>
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
assuming

> item.isRecordActive==0   --->   must be disabled
>
> item.isRecordActive!=0   --->   must be enabled

```
@if (item.isRecordActive == 0) {
    @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", ViewBag.ListItems, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) 
} 
else
{
    @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", ViewBag.ListItems) 
}
```